# Por que tengo este Error en Angular?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Angular 9, recientemente ya no puedo desplegarlo
porque me sale este error.

Inicialmente me salia que no identificaba un ID luego comenté algunas secciones
del proyecto y volvi a compilar, ahora me sale este error.

Hasta donde investigué, tiene que ver con el AppMODULE.TS

La traza de error es:

```
**  compiler.js:2281 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'FormControl' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:2281)
        at compiler.js:20987
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:20962)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:26724)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26707)
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:26669)
        at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:224)
        at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (core.js:41948)
        at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:42342)

**
```

Primero me salía un Uncaught error con 'id', luego coomente algunas secciones que tenian id, porque no encontraba el error,
ahora me salta este error.

este es mi appmodule.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './shared/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer/footer.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CategoriaComponent } from './components/parametricos/categoria/categoria.component';
import { CategoriaEditComponent } from './components/parametricos/categoria/categoria-edit.component';
import { MediosPagoComponent } from './components/parametricos/medios-pago/medios-pago.component';
import { MediosPagoEditComponent } from './components/parametricos/medios-pago/medios-pago-edit.component';
import { CategoriaListarComponent } from './components/parametricos/categoria/categoria-listar.component';
import { MediosPagoListarComponent } from './components/parametricos/medios-pago/medios-pago-listar.component';
import { ClienteEditComponent } from './components/parametricos/cliente/cliente-edit.component';
import { ClienteListarComponent } from './components/parametricos/cliente/cliente-listar.component';
import { ProductoComponent } from './components/parametricos/producto/producto.component';
import { ProductoEditComponent } from './components/parametricos/producto/producto-edit.component';
import { ProductoListarComponent } from './components/parametricos/producto/producto-listar.component';
import { ProductoListar2Component } from './components/parametricos/producto/producto-listar2.component';
import { ReservaComponent } from './components/parametricos/reserva/reserva.component';
import { ReservEditComponent } from './components/parametricos/reserva/reserv-edit.component';
import { ReservaListComponent } from './components/parametricos/reserva/reserva-list.component';
import { ServicioComponent } from './components/parametricos/servicio/servicio.component';
import { ServicioListarComponent } from './components/parametricos/servicio/servicio-listar.component';
import { ServicioEditComponent } from './components/parametricos/servicio/servicio-edit.component';
import { EmpleadoComponent } from './components/parametricos/empleado/empleado.component';
import { EmpleadoEditComponent } from './components/parametricos/empleado/empleado-edit.component';
import { EmpleadoListarComponent } from './components/parametricos/empleado/empleado-listar.component';
import { CategoriaListar2Component } from './components/parametricos/categoria/categoria-listar2.component';
import { ServicioListar2Component } from './components/parametricos/servicio/servicio-listar2.component';
```

(otro bloque de código)

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        SidebarComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        CategoriaComponent,
        CategoriaEditComponent,
        MediosPagoComponent,
        MediosPagoEditComponent,
        CategoriaListarComponent,
        MediosPagoListarComponent,
        ProductoComponent,
        ClienteEditComponent,
        ClienteListarComponent,
        ProductoEditComponent,
        ProductoListarComponent,
        ReservaComponent,
        ReservEditComponent,
        ReservaListComponent,
        ServicioComponent,
        ServicioListarComponent,
        ServicioEditComponent,
        EmpleadoComponent,
        EmpleadoEditComponent,
        EmpleadoListarComponent,
        CategoriaListar2Component,
        ProductoListar2Component,
        ServicioListar2Component
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgbModule,
        NgSelectModule,
        NgxPaginationModule,
        FormControl, FormsModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Este es el error:

> compiler.js:2281 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'FormControl'
> imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tienen idea de que puede andar mal?

Comment: Este es el error: compiler.js:2281 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'FormControl' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: Puedes agregar el error en la pregunta?

Comment: `FormControl` no es un módulo, comprueba eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje puede aparecer por duplicar modulos importados.
En este caso debe ser porque FormControl ya es importado por [ReactiveFormsModule](https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule) (este es el @NgModule a importar, remover imports de FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup por ejemplo)

Cambia a:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Y quita `,FormControl, FormsModule` de `imports:`

Comment: Lo he probado, pero a consecuencia me tira otro error que supongo qee es por haberle quitado el FormContor, FormModule,:

Comment: Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("
    
    <!-- Navbar Search-->
    [ERROR ->]<form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ml-auto mr-0 mr-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
        <div cl"): ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.html@49:4

Comment: Comente el buscador, y automaticamente deployó el proyecto! ha funcionado! muchas gracias!! :)